# Mainactivity.kt is not recognizing the ID in Android studio kotlin

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to run Android app in kotlin. But Mainactivity.kt is not recognizing the ID in Android studio kotlin.

[image]

[image]

I have tried many ways doing this to solve this error.
i even tried to go in build and click on clean project,
then, rebuild projects.

but the error wouldn't budge it is still there.
i have entered the id of TextView in MainActivity.kt but it still showing in red!

how may i resolve it please help!

Comment: Did you try running the app? Please share your logcat

Comment: Have you imported the corresponding layout file of your activity?
Like this: 
`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.your_layout_file_name.*`

Comment: @mayank1513 sir i have tried running the app, it is showing unresolved reference.

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee while importing it is showing error in Mainactivity to Kotlinx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code for Kotlin version 1.4.1 and it worked perfectly well.

To resolve your error, you can use `val tv:TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_content)` and use tv in your code.

Second option is that you `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20"` in your build.gradle file to `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10"`

As stated by @Jimale Abdi -

> kotlinx.android.synthetic is no longer a recommended practice. Removing
> in favour of explicit findViewById.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`kotlin synthetic` is no longer available. In `Kotlin 1.4.20-M2` JetBrains deprecated Kotlin Android Extensions compiler plugin. instead, use `findViewById` or `ViewBinding` for more info check [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42121) issue also check [this](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/882241) commit

Comment: Please post relevant source

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `findViewById()`

Declare a `tv_content` variable in your class:

```
private lateinit var tv_content: TextView
```

In onCreate add:

```
tv_content = findViewById(R.id.tv_content)
```

Now in your `Update` funcrion you can call:

```
tv_content.text = "Text you want to set"
```

Comment: where is the Update Function can u tell me ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by using dataBinging. Follow the steps below

1. Add **data binding** in Gradle Script >>> **build.gradle(Module.yourAppName.app)**

```
        release {
          ........
          ........
         
        }
    }
    //add your code here
    dataBinding{
        enabled  = true
    }
```

2. Sync the project
3. add <**layout**> tag in **activity_main.xml** layout

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize= "30sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

4. In **MainActicity.kt** add the data binding code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding //binding variable

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_news) //binding content view


    }
    fun update(view: View){
        binding.tv_content.text = "your text goes here" //apply the binding to text
      }

}
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

just open you build gradle app file.
and replace your plugins to

```
plugins {
     id 'com.android.application'
     id 'kotlin-android'
     id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to added plugin kotlin("android.extensions")  to build.gradle(Module)